# Issue when integrating Windows AD with Redhat Linux

Tags: windows, domain

I use Windows server 2012 R2 - AD and DNS server and Linux machine Redhat 7.

I need to integrate Windows AD and Linux authentication.

kinit setup have been setup and klist show the AD user name information.

Now when I give `net ads join -U Administrator`

```
kinit succeeded but ads_sasl_spnego_krb5_bind failed: Server not found in Kerberos database
```

I get the above error, and I cannot go past this error.

Comment: I can give more information or configuration files if needed

Comment: Please include these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the password server and Realm. I reversed the entry.

```
[global]
   workgroup = bright


   password server = AD.domain.local
   realm = domain.LOCAL
   encrypt passwords = yes
   winbind enum groups = yes
   winbind enum users = yes
   winbind use default domain = yes
   security = ADS
   debuglevel = 2
   wins support = no
   idmap uid = 10000-20000
   idmap gid = 10000-20000
   template shell = /bin/false
   winbind offline logon = false
```

Now after getting the information from `net config workstation` command in Windows AD server.

I'm able to join the Domain.